# Being considered for two roles of different seniority in same department-- how do I communicate that I’m only interested in the higher role?

Tags: interviewing

Applied for a Influencer Marketing job and turns out it's a catchall position for a 15-person team they're building. Interview performance determines your position.

I've been told I would probably come in as a Lead or Director, and all things considered, I think Director would be the best fit for my background. However, I don't have formal experience in this field. It's influencer marketing. My strengths and weaknesses:

- I've been a top influencer for 7 years, and I think that's the
  foundation for success in the role
- Built and led 6 person team
- Worked with a dozen marketing teams over the years
- I don't have formal marketing experience

I think I'll get an offer for the company for sure. But while I want them to seriously consider me for the higher role, I think they're very incentivized to consider me for the lower role. However, I have offers elsewhere that would make the lower role unappealing.

How do I respectfully communicate I'd only like to be considered for the higher role?

Comment: If you have communicated your strengths and achievements, and have decided that you would reject the lower role, then say "I'd only like to be considered for the higher role."

Comment: Do you have any information on exactly what the differences between the two positions are?

Comment: @dwizum After posting this, I actually had a conversation and learned about some key differences about who reports to who, and success milestones for each role.

Comment: I edited the title of your question to better reflect the body. Let me know if this is inaccurate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How do I respectfully communicate I'd only like to be considered for
>   the higher role?

If you are interviewing through a recruiter, you make it known to the recruiter that you are very interested in the company, but that you would only consider accepting a Director role, and aren't interested in a Lead role. The recruiter would be expected to convey your wishes to the company, then let you know if you should continue with the process or not.

If you aren't working with a recruiter, you should express the same to HR or the hiring manager - whichever you meet first.

Before doing all this, make sure this is what you actually want, since it would almost certainly drop you out of the running for a Lead position. This way you won't be wasting any of their time, or yours.

With all of this, I'm assuming you actually know what is involved with the role of Director at this specific company, and probably what is required of the Lead role here as well. If you don't, you must specifically ask about this first before you decide it's a role you want.

> However, I don't have formal experience in this field.

Many companies would only hire Directors with significant domain expertise. For some it might not matter as much.

Similarly, many companies would only hire Directors with formal management experience. For some it might not matter as much.

Seems like you'll find out soon enough about this particular company.